# InstallShield 2008 Pro with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, installshield

I'm having an old version of InstallShield 2008 Pro which work perfect with my Visual Studio 2008 Pro 32bit application deployment.

I'm moving towards Visual Studio 2012 with porting application to x64.

I could not find much information on InstallShield 2008 from the flexira website. With next to 0 experience in InstallShield I have a couple of questions regarding the deployment -

1. Is InstallShield 2008 is sufficient to cater Visual Studio 2012 with x64 upgarde.
2. Do I need to upgrade to InstallShield 2012 or better off looking at open/free project like WiX.

Any other comments are welcome in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

For supported InstallShield integration with Visual Studio 2012, you will need InstallShield 2012 Spring or later. Integration nets you the use of project output groups; if you are willing to do without those, you can use InstallShield outside of Visual Studio, and the primary concern is which versions of Windows you need to support and how cleanly.